# How do I get going with Haskell on my computer?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm learning my first functional programming language but having some trouble with the initial logistics (the professor basically said, "get it set up somehow" and didn't provide much detail.)

Anyway, I have Mac OS X version 10.6.8. To start out, I installed GHC in my home directory and found that I could open it with the command "ghci" in terminal. From there (excuse my utter lack of knowledge), I followed the vague instructions in the syllabus and opened another window with the a1.hs file I am to modify for an assignment. When I was done defining a function, I typed the command "ghc a1-skeleton.hs" to open the interpreter with that loaded into it (that's what I would be doing, right?) but got this error:

```
a1.hs:5:8:
    Could not find module `System'
    It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.1'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I'm guessing this is like missing an "#include" or something similar in a language like C++. Do I just need to find/add something to a particular directory?

Also, since I didn't catch on right away with this stuff, what exactly does the interpreter do? Is it a program that skips 'compiling' in the procedural language sense and just tries to follow the commands in a .hs file straight away?

Thanks!

UPDATE:: The code that seems to be the issue:

```
  2 module Main where
  3 
  4 import Test.HUnit
  5 import System
```

Comment: Please post your code, it'll help us understand the error

Comment: Amusingly, one of my professors just did exactly the same thing with OCaml. I already had it installed, luckily, but I imagine some of the other students are having similar problems right now--I remember initially getting OCaml to work was even harder than getting Haskell up and running. (Actually, getting Haskell to work was not all too bad, all told.)

Comment: Also, I'm a little jealous that you have a class in Haskell--OCaml is the closest I've found at my university and I had to go quite a ways to get to it :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your minor question:

ghci also does compilation, but unlike the non-interactive ghc it doesn't create efficient machine code, but instead compiles to a simpler internal bytecode which is then directly interpreted.  Basically ghci is optimized for doing quick compilation (as you would want for quick development) rather than making the result run fast.

In addition it contains other useful stuff for interactive use such as a read-eval-print loop and a debugger.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is probably that the `System` module is the old, non-hierarchical name. I think you now need to use modules called something like `System.Environment` (depending on the exact function you want to import).

Since you haven't used any functions from those modules, I can't tell you exactly what to import. In GHCi, you can view which functions a module defines like this:

```
Prelude> :browse System.Environment
getArgs :: IO [String]
getEnv :: String -> IO String
getEnvironment :: IO [(String, String)]
getProgName :: IO String
withArgs :: [String] -> IO a -> IO a
withProgName :: String -> IO a -> IO a
```

You could try getting rid of the `import System` statement and loading the file. You should then get some identifiers that are not in scope. Now you can input these into [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) (which will be your best friend, coincidentally) to see where they are defined.

My understanding is that the functions from the old `System` module are now in [`System.Environment`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/System-Environment.html), [`System.Process`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/process-1.1.0.1/System-Process.html) and [`System.Exit`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4-latest/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/System-Exit.html). If you don't want to think too deeply about it, you could just import all three :P.

Comment: If the professor insists on Haskell98 because it's 'standard' or for some other reason - it will be pain to convert old modules to hierarchical ones for every skeleton.

Comment: And by the way, the latest standard is [Haskell 2010](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Language_and_library_specification#The_Haskell_2010_report).

Answer (score 3):

You've just installed GHC -- you'll probably want to install the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/) instead -- this is the "batteries-included" version of the GHC. It comes with a lot of packages you'll need, and it also provides `cabal`, which is a package manager for Haskell. This way, you'll avoid a lot of the "Could not find modue" errors that you'll otherwise run into.

Being a one-click install doesn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to open it with `ghci -package haskell98 a1-skeleton.hs` in terminal. If it doesn't work, include full `a1-skeleton.hs` in your question.

Comment: Yes, or `-XHaskell98` instead of `-package haskell98`, or add `{-# LANGUAGE Haskell98 #-}` to the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

1) It is better to install haskell platform, not GHC alone. It is pain in ass to work without cabal-install available and building it ain't always easy, especially on recent ghc version.

2) ghc uses sophisticated packaging system - cabal. `System` module is exported by Haskell98 package, that is masked by default and should be enabled explicitly. For ghc and ghci it is done using `-package` switch (see online docs for ghc)

3) it is probably better to utilize `base` package rather `Haskell98` or `Haskell2010`.

===

ghci compiles sources to byte-code, which is not saved on disk by default. It also link any foreign libraries/packages if needed and in some specific cases may fail doing it.